# Why i can't see the functions from my script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to use a script with a onclick event but whenever I drag it to Unity I can't see the functions I set in that script. I can only see the defaultasset function.That happened to me many times with other scripts.What could be the issue?
Sorry if that is a silly question. I'm very new to Unity and C#.

[image]

I wanted to use this function that is inside my script:

```
 public void OpenPDF(string PDFNameWithExtension)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SaveTemplatePDF(PDFNameWithExtension, "application/pdf"));
    }
```

[image]

Assets is the parent directory of Streaming Assets
[image]

Full script if it helps.As you can see it is just a script to open a pdf or image:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityAndroidOpenUrl;
using UnityEngine;

public class DemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string MAIN_DIR = "/storage/emulated/0";
    private const string testFolderName = "TotalPower";
    // private const string PDFName = "template.pdf";

    private static string pathToTestFolder;
    private static string pathToTemplatePDF;

    private void Start()
    {
        pathToTestFolder = Path.Combine(MAIN_DIR, testFolderName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathToTestFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToTestFolder);
        }
    }


    public void OpenPDF(string PDFNameWithExtension)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SaveTemplatePDF(PDFNameWithExtension, "application/pdf"));
    }

    public void OpenImage(string imageNameWithExtension)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SaveTemplatePDF(imageNameWithExtension, "application/png"));
    }


    private IEnumerator SaveTemplatePDF(string PDFName, string dataType)
    {

        string localPathToTemplatePDF = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, PDFName);
        WWW www = new WWW(localPathToTemplatePDF);
        yield return www;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error while loading template PDF: " + www.error);
            yield break;
        }
        pathToTemplatePDF = Path.Combine(pathToTestFolder, PDFName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(pathToTemplatePDF, www.bytes);

        AndroidOpenUrl.OpenFile(pathToTemplatePDF, dataType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218362/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-why-i-cant-see-the-functions-from-my-script-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following plugin i found on github: https://github.com/Mihail5412/Unity-Android-Files-Opener

My project was missing AndroidOpenUrl.cs and that is why it did not work

Also the scripts should not be inside StreamingAssets folder and only the files you want to display